# Filter and if result is x, replace with y, or if result is a, replace with b

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to perform a filter and then depending on the Yes or No result, change it to a status.

If the result is yes it should say "Signed", if the result is No it should say "Awaiting".

I have attached an example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UVotQjJ4Z1EVbQGnQ6J6-nhrRAY_Kbu1LvB746U95T8/edit?usp=sharing

- Sheet 1 has 3 columns:

**Name | Type | Contract Signed**

Name1 | Triangle | Yes

Name2 | Circle | Yes

Name3 | Triangle | No

- Sheet 2 only shows those of type triangle and has 2 columns:

**Name | Contract Status**

Name1 | Signed

Name2 | Awaiting

So far I can manage to get the first one to say "Signed" by using the following formula:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(filter(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!B:B="Triangle"),"Yes","Signed")
```

But I am stuck on trying to get another level deeper and if the answer is "No" it should make it "Awaiting".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!C:C,"Yes","Signed"),"No","Awaiting")
```

Comment: Doesn't quite seem to work, I think because it is not performing the filter as well? I have enabled Edit access on the sheet.

Comment: Sorry, missed the "Triangle" condition part of it.
Please try this:
`=IF(Sheet1!B:B="Triangle", if(Sheet1!C:C="Yes","Signed","Awaiting"),"")`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the following formula appears to work:

```
=arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(filter(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!B:B="Triangle"),"Yes","Signed"),"No","Awaiting"))
```